# Is std::pair<int, std::string> ordering well-defined?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

It seems that I can sort a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`, and it will sort based on the int value. Is this a well defined thing to do?

Does `std::pair` have a default ordering based on its elements?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`std::pair` uses lexicographic comparison: It will compare based on the first element. If the values of the first elements are equal, it will then compare based on the second element.

The definition in the C++03 standard (section 20.2.2) is:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator<(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y);

Returns: x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second < y.second).
```

Comment: Why they don't use a simpler (y.first >= x.first) instead of less + negation ?

Comment: @PatrickRoncagliolo This way only requires user-defined types to implement `operator<` to support ordering. Otherwise they'd need to support more ordering operators, and ensure the relations between them (e.g. `>=` is the negation of `<`).

Comment: So it is not an optimization trick of some sort related to the efficiency of < vs <=. Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

According to my copy of the C++0x standard, section 20.3.3.26, `std::pair` has an `operator<` defined such that for two pairs x and y, it returns

```
x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second < y.second)
```

I'm not certain if this is part of the 2003 standard as well.  I should also note that this won't compile if the elements themselves are not LessThanComparable.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation from SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/pair.html)

> The comparison operator. It uses lexicographic comparison: the return value is true if the first element of x is less than the first element of y, and false if the first element of y is less than the first element of x. If neither of these is the case, then operator< returns the result of comparing the second elements of x and y. This operator may only be used if both T1 and T2 are LessThanComparable. This is a global function, not a member function.

Looks like it's actually a combination of both elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  `operator<()` is defined for `std::pair<T1, T2>`, assuming that both `T1` and `T2` are themselves comparable.