# how to use std::pair as the key std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I want to define a `std::map` with key as `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` something like follow

`typedef std::map< std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string> my_map`

Is this allowed, and how do i write `comparasion operator` for such map.

Comment: What happens when you ... try it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed? How would you write a comparison operator for `std::map<KType, VType>`?

Comment: How does your C++ platform document `std::pair`? Answer is there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.

`std::pair` already has an `operator<` which compares the two values in order, so you may not need to do anything special for a comparator at all.

Comment: Bah, you beat me...  Now to delete my suboptimal answer!

Comment: It's worth to mention, that it is only defined for lexicographic comparison. So for a pair of `int`s you would have to define it on your own.

Comment: @visitor: found nothing official, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined

Comment: @ezdazuzena Why would that mean that you need to define your own comparison for pairs of ints? Isn't that the behavior you'd want for pairs of ints in the majority of cases?

Comment: @sepp2k: I could really miss something here, put in lexicographic comparison the following is true: 101 < 11

Comment: @ezdazuzena It doesn't compare the individual items lexicographically (how could you even implement that generically?). All that's meant by lexicographically here is that it compares by the first element and if the first element is equal by the second. For the comparison of the individual elements it uses the elements' `operator<`.

Comment: @sepp2k: hmm.. can't argue further against that. So, I'll believe you and I guess I learned something new. Thanks then..