# c++ vector two sided sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a vector with pairs of string and integer (count), I sorted everything according to count, but I have to sort also the strings if there are 2 or more repetitions in the list. For example;

3 trial
2 yummy
2 abc

So, there are 2 2's in the list, therefore abc must come before yummy. My code looks like this:

```
vector<pair<string, int> > values(hash_table.begin(), hash_table.end());

sort(values.begin(), values.end(), sort_reverse);


bool sort_reverse(const pair<string, int> &a, const pair<string, int> &b) {
  return a.second > b.second;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to take the values itself into account.

```
bool sort_reverse(const pair<string, int> &a, const pair<string, int> &b) {
    return (a.second > b.second) || ((a.second == b.second) && (a.first > b.first));
}
```

Comment: why should this be wrong ? he's searching for a sorting like
1: "3 trail"
2: "2 abc"   (2 entry cause of leading 'a')
3: "2 yummy" (3 entry cause of leading 'y')

Comment: thanks for upvoting again ;) i realy don't know why it was downvoted ... no comment :P
@Jason: np, yw

Comment: Because it does not satisfy a strict weak ordering, which is a requirement for the sort algorithm. This is technically undefined behaviour.

Comment: This does _not_ work; as @juanchopanza states, this will fail completely on some data.

Comment: could you make an example plz. i've no idea where this could fail ? it's bigger or not bigger ... if second is not bigger it's false anyway and if second is bigger it depends on first which may be bigger or not...

Comment: if you compare `("apple", 2)` and `("banana", 2)` it will return `false`.

Comment: ty, i've modified my answer

Answer (score 7):

You can invert the sorting of any range by using a greater-than comparison instead of the default less-than:

```
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), std::greater<std::pair<string, int>>());
```

Alternatively, you can reverse the order of iteration:

```
std::sort(values.rbegin(), values.rend());
```

**Edit** If you want to change the comparison criteria to compare lexicographically by the pair's `second` first and it's `first` next, you can provide your own comparison function. It must still satisfy [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) as in the examples above. Lexicographical comparisons are trivial to implement with `std::tie`:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct pair_backwards_greater
{
  bool operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1, T2>& rhs) const
  {
    return std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first) > std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);
  }
};
```

then

```
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), pair_backwards_greater<string, int>());
```

You also have the option of using a simple lambda expression instead of writing the functor by hand:

```
  std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(),
            [](const std::pair<std::string, int> &lhs, const std::pair<std::string, int> &rhs) 
            {
              return std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first) > std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first); 
            }  
           );
```

`std::tie` requires C++11 library support, but there are C++03 alternative implementations in `boost::tie` and `std::tr1::tie`. Lambda expressions require C++11 language support.

Comment: +1 or `rbegin()` and `rend()` just to see if the class grader is paying attention.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. Actually, I am sorting the elements according to their count. And I want to just sort the strings if there are 2 or more elements that have the same count. So, in this case your solution doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: @Jason what is "their count"? As far as I understand this solves the problem.

Comment: So there are 2 pairs. Pair 1-> "test" has count 2, and pair 2-> "asd" has count 2. First of all I was comparing them according to their count, but now I have to compare them both according to their count and alphabethical order.

Comment: @Jason ah OK, so you want to compare them by the `int` first and the `string` second? I will edit my answer.

Comment: if i understand him right he want the sorting with the string too.he's searching for a sorting like 1: "3 trail" 2: "2 abc" (2 entry cause of leading 'a') 3: "2 yummy" (3 entry cause of leading 'y'). i added a solution for this.

Comment: @Alex yeah, he's got it. count first, string secondary. it'll be up in  a minute.

Answer (score 4):

To sort on both fields in one hit:

```
bool sort_pair(const std::pair<std::string, int> &a, const std::pair<std::string, int> &b) 
{
    return (a.second > b.second) ||  
        ( 
            (a.second == b.second)  &&
            (a.first > b.first)
    );
}

void sortVector(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >& values)
{
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), sort_pair);
}
```

See also [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined)  entry

Comment: Yes and I was looking for this only :D

Comment: @P0W Exactly; really the ordering for a pair<> is canonical, only normally the primary ordering would be based on `first` rather than `second`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose an alternative, which is slightly different, and introduces the benefits of `stable_sort`.

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> CNP;

bool byName(CNP const& left, CNP const& right) { return left.second < right.second; }
bool byCount(CNP const& left, CNP const& right) { return left.first < right.first; }

std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), byName);

std::stable_sort(values.begin(), values.end(), byCount);
```

This works because in case of equivalent elements (elements that compare equal) `stable_sort` preserve their relative order (which `sort` may, but does not guarantee).

Thus, imagining that you have `[ (3, "apple"), (2, "zorro"), (2, "banana") ]`:

- sort by name yields: `[ (3, "apple"), (2, "banana"), (2, "zorro") ]`
- stable sort by count: `[ (2, "banana"), (2, "zorro"), (3, "apple") ]`

It is of course more efficient to use a single sort with a more complicated predicate if you have no need for the intermediate step; however if you receive a list already sorted by name, then just applying the `stable_sort` by count might be faster.

Finally, a simple trick to check whether a list is sorted accorded to a criterion (or not):

```
template <typename C, typename P>
bool is_sorted(C const& list, P comp) {
    typedef typename C::const_reference CR;

    auto const reversed = [](CR left, CR right) { return comp(right, left);  };

    return std::adjacent_find(list.begin(), list.end(), reversed) == list.end();
}
```

Note: C++11 has a `is_sorted` method, though expressed in terms of iterators and not container of course.

Comment: This is a pretty useful suggestion. BTW it is worth mentioning that there is an `std::is_sorted` in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oh! I did not know!