# How can I sort a std::map first by value, then by key?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, key

I need to sort a `std::map` by value, then by key. The map contains data like the following:

```
  1  realistically
  8         really
  4         reason
  3     reasonable
  1     reasonably
  1     reassemble
  1    reassembled
  2      recognize
 92         record
 48        records
  7           recs
```

I need to get the values in order, but the kicker is that the keys need to be in alphabetical order after the values are in order. How can I do this?

Comment: do you use a std::map to store the data ?

Comment: Put the std::pair<int, std::string>s into a list, and sort it.

Comment: @Raxvan yes, its stored in a map.

Comment: @Wilbert I know that would put the values in order, but then would it keep the keys in alphabetical order after sorting the values?

Comment: sort on pairs sorts on first, then second item. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined)

Comment: value only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699060/stl-map-sort-by-value

Comment: @TrevorHutto You can use `std::multimap` with your `values` as `keys` since it allows duplicate keys and will work with `std::sort`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`std::map` will sort its elements by `keys`. It doesn't care about the `values` when sorting.

<s>You can use `std::vector<std::pair<K,V>>` then sort it using `std::sort` followed by `std::stable_sort`:</s>

```
std::vector<std::pair<K,V>> items;

//fill items

//sort by value using std::sort
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), value_comparer);

//sort by key using std::stable_sort
std::stable_sort(items.begin(), items.end(), key_comparer);
```

The first sort should use `std::sort` since it is `nlog(n)`, and then use `std::stable_sort` which is `n(log(n))^2` in the worst case.

Note that while `std::sort` is chosen for performance reason, `std::stable_sort` is needed for correct ordering, as you want the order-by-value to be preserved.

---

@gsf noted in the comment, you could use *only* `std::sort` if you choose a comparer which compares `values` first, and IF they're equal, sort the `keys`.

```
auto cmp = [](std::pair<K,V> const & a, std::pair<K,V> const & b) 
{ 
     return a.second != b.second?  a.second < b.second : a.first < b.first;
};
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), cmp);
```

That should be efficient.

But wait, there is a better approach: store `std::pair<V,K>` instead of `std::pair<K,V>` and then you don't need any comparer at all — the standard comparer for `std::pair` would be enough, as it compares `first` (which is `V`) first then `second` which is `K`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<V,K>> items;
//...
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end());
```

That should work great.

Comment: Would the efficiency of the sort be hurt if I add to the vector in alphabetical order like I have it now?

Comment: Oh I see, it wouldn't because you are sorting on value first?

Comment: @TrevorHutto: If one (either `key` or `value`) is sorted, then you need only `stable_sort` to sort the other which is not sorted.

Comment: That is very bad way to do this. Instead use only one sort but provide compare predicate that compares the keys and in case they are equal compares the value.

Comment: I don't think I can apply that in this situation. You may tell me differently. But I have functions that add to the map, but if that is already contained in the map it increases the value by one, how can I do that when I'm looking up by the frequency and trying to do something to the string?

Comment: In other words, I don't think switching the key and value will help me much.

Comment: I got it working with the last solution in your answer, works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: The data is in map. 
auto cmp = [](std::pair<K,V> const & a, std::pair<K,V> const & b) 
{ 
     return a.second != b.second?  a.second < b.second : a.first < b.first;
};
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), cmp);

items is not map.

Comment: @Nawaz How `there is a better approach: store std::pair<V,K> instead of std::pair<K,V> and then you don't need any comparer at all` would even work if you want to extract a value based on key?

Comment: @Nawaz I cant see how this would work. Values will be unique so same values will be dropped from map. This should only work with `std::multimap`

Comment: @BugShotGG: You asked about extracting value *based on key*  and that sounds like: given a key (which is unique), you want to extract the corresponding value.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `std::set` instead of `std::map`.

You can store both key and value in `std::pair` and the type of container will look like this:

```
std::set< std::pair<int, std::string> > items;
```

`std::set` will sort it's values both by original keys and values that were stored in `std::map`.

Comment: This isn't the case here: the input is map. That might be for various reasons, e.g., values are occurrence of strings in database etc. We can't use set in such cases because set::insert() will treat ("foo", 1) & ("foo", 2) different items.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in *Nawaz's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19842086/2675154), you cannot sort your map by itself as you need it, because `std::map` sorts its elements based on the keys only. So, you need a different container, but if you have to stick to your map, then you can still copy its content (temporarily) into another data structure.

I think, the best solution is to use a `std::set` storing flipped key-value pairs as presented in *ks1322's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19842744/2675154).
The `std::set` is sorted by default and the [order of the pairs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) is exactly as you need it:

> 3) If `lhs.first<rhs.first`, returns `true`. Otherwise, if `rhs.first<lhs.first`, returns `false`. Otherwise, if `lhs.second<rhs.second`, returns `true`. Otherwise, returns `false`.

This way you don't need an additional sorting step and the resulting code is quite short:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;  // Your original map.
m["realistically"] = 1;
m["really"]        = 8;
m["reason"]        = 4;
m["reasonable"]    = 3;
m["reasonably"]    = 1;
m["reassemble"]    = 1;
m["reassembled"]   = 1;
m["recognize"]     = 2;
m["record"]        = 92;
m["records"]       = 48;
m["recs"]          = 7;

std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>> s;  // The new (temporary) container.

for (auto const &kv : m)
    s.emplace(kv.second, kv.first);  // Flip the pairs.

for (auto const &vk : s)
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << vk.first << std::setw(15) << vk.second << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
  1  realistically
  1     reasonably
  1     reassemble
  1    reassembled
  2      recognize
  3     reasonable
  4         reason
  7           recs
  8         really
 48        records
 92         record
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/mRBpXh)

Note: Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) you can use [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) together with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) for iterating over a map.
As a result, the code for copying your map becomes even shorter and more readable:

```
for (auto const &[k, v] : m)
    s.emplace(v, k);  // Flip the pairs.
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` already sorts the values using a predicate you define or `std::less` if you don't provide one.  `std::set` will also store items in order of the of a define comparator. However neither set nor map allow you to have multiple keys.  I would suggest defining a `std::map<int,std::set<string>` if you want to accomplish this using your data structure alone.  You should also realize that `std::less` for string will sort lexicographically not alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The other two answers make a good point. I'm assuming that you want to order them into some other structure, or in order to print them out.

"Best" can mean a number of different things. Do you mean "easiest," "fastest," "most efficient," "least code," "most readable?"

The most obvious approach is to loop through twice. On the first pass, order the values:

```
if(current_value > examined_value)
{
    current_value = examined_value
    (and then swap them, however you like)
}
```

Then on the second pass, alphabetize the words, but only if their values match.

```
if(current_value == examined_value)
{
    (alphabetize the two)
}
```

Strictly speaking, this is a "bubble sort" which is slow because every time you make a swap, you have to start over. One "pass" is finished when you get through the whole list without making any swaps.

There are other sorting algorithms, but the principle would be the same: order by value, then alphabetize.