# How to preserve insertion order in Map?

Tags: c++, maps

I am trying to make a map of string and integer like this

```
map<string,int>m;
```

Insertion is going something like

```
m["sunday"]=52;
m["monday"]=51;
...
...
...
```

**But** whenever i try to iterate it using iterator like this

```
 map<string,int>::iterator it;

 for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end;it++)
 cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second;
```

The output is not like the input inserted.I want to know how to maintain the insertion order in **c++** .I searched the web and i found same question but on java.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842035/stdmap-how-to-sort-by-value-then-by-key

Comment: I cant use boost.And my task is quite simply that's why i thought that making map and keeping track would be quite hard to implement.Is this the only way.Not something like LinkedHashMaps

Comment: @amahfouz i can't sort them.It will change the question's demand

Comment: If you can't use boost or sort, then perhaps a `vector< pair< string, int> >` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Not really getting it..maybe you would like to expand it sir,

Comment: @twalberg:  I know this question is way old... but +1 for a suggestion that uses existing capabilities to simply accomplish the purpose.