# C++ Sort Map By Value Numerically, Key Alphabetically

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to make this frequency table with c++, and my code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> mypair;

struct IntCmp {
    bool operator()(const mypair &lhs, const mypair &rhs) {
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
};

string removeSpaces(string input) {
    input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(),input.end(),' '),input.end());
    input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(), input.end(), '\t'), input.end());
    input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(), input.end(), '.'), input.end());
    return input;
}

void printmap(const std::map<std::string,int> &mymap, int size) {
    std::vector<mypair> myvec(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
    assert(myvec.size() >= size);
    std::partial_sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.begin() + size, myvec.end(), IntCmp());

    for(int i = size; i --> 0;) {
        std::cout << myvec[i].first << " " << myvec[i].second << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    string str;

    cout << "Enter text:\n";
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Frequencies:\n";

    str = "do be do bo.";

    str = removeSpaces(str);
    int size = str.size();
    string *array = new string[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array[i] = str[i];
    }
    sort(array, array+size);
    map<int, string> mymap;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        mymap[i] = array[i];
    }
    map<string, int> freq;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if(freq.count(mymap[i]) == 0) {
            //Not found
            freq[mymap[i]] = 1;
        }
        else {
            //Found
            freq.at(mymap[i]) = freq.at(mymap[i]) + 1;
        }
    }
    int mapsize = freq.size();
    printmap(freq, mapsize);
}
```

When I run the code with the `str` given as `do be do bo.`, the output is as follows

```
o 3
d 2
b 2
e 1
```

So here's my thought process.

I take the input `str` and put it in an array, and sort that array alphabetically, and then put that array into the map `mymap`. Then, I take `mymap` and get the frequency of each string and put the letters as the keys and the frequency as the values in the map `freq`. Then, I use the `printmap()` function to order the map by value descending.

However, when I do this, the keys are randomly ordered. So, for example, in the string presented above, `b 2` is printed out after `d 2`, even though they were in order when I gave the `freq` map to the `printmap()` function.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to sort the map in the `printmap()` function by value, and then by key, so the results are printed out by descending value and alphabetical key.

The desired result for the `do be do bo.` is as follows:

```
o 3
b 2
d 2
e 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::map, how to sort by value, then by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842035/stdmap-how-to-sort-by-value-then-by-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `std::partial_sort` here - it's meant for sorting only part of the input. Try `std::stable_sort` instead: it will sort the input, but will not affect the order of elements that compare equal. This gives you what you want since your input `map` is already sorted by increasing alphabetical key:

```
struct IntCmp {
    bool operator()(const mypair &lhs, const mypair &rhs) {
        return lhs.second > rhs.second; // note reversed comparison here to sort by descending order
    }
};

void printmap(const std::map<std::string,int> &mymap, int size) {
    std::vector<mypair> myvec(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
    assert(myvec.size() >= size);
    std::stable_sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), IntCmp());

    // note we now iterate forwards because the sort comparison is reversed
    for(const auto &item : myvec) {
        std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could alter your comparison function to compare both the value and the key, and use a plain `std::sort`:

```
struct IntCmp {
    bool operator()(const mypair &lhs, const mypair &rhs) {
        if(lhs.second == rhs.second) return lhs.first < rhs.first; // this is the "secondary" comparison, used if the frequencies are equal
        return lhs.second > rhs.second; // note reversed comparison here to sort by descending order
    }
};

void printmap(const std::map<std::string,int> &mymap, int size) {
    std::vector<mypair> myvec(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
    assert(myvec.size() >= size);
    std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), IntCmp());

    // note we now iterate forwards because the sort comparison is reversed
    for(const auto &item : myvec) {
        std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << "\n";
    }
}
```