# How does std::sort work for list of pairs?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, std

Why does [this](http://ideone.com/tkYavT):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>                                                             
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, string>> list;

int main() {
    int one = 1, two = 2, three =3, five =5, six = 6;
    string bla = "bla";

    list.push_back( pair<int, string>(two, bla));
    list.push_back( pair<int, string>(one, bla));
    list.push_back( pair<int, string>(two, bla));
    list.push_back( pair<int, string>(six, bla));
    list.push_back( pair<int, string>(five, bla));

    sort(list.begin(), list.end());

    for(auto item : list) {
        cout << item.first << endl;
    }
}
```

work as intended? output is:

```
1
2
2
5
6
```

How `std::sort` gets how to sort my `int-string` pairs? How to make it do so for some class of mine as pair `first`? Is there a way to sort by `second` using `std::sort`?

Comment: `std::pair` has a `operator<`. If you want `std::sort` to sort differently, give it a comparator.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Comment: You may try providing a specialization for the `bool operator<int,string><(const& std::pair<int,string> op1,const& std::pair<int,string> op2)` function, and pass this for sorting.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined

Comment: @MarkRansom He's got a `vector` named *list*. `std::sort` doesn't work with `std::list` since it requires RandomAccessIterators.

Comment: @Praetorian I thought `std::sort` would work in a degraded state with bidirectional iterators. I must be thinking of something else, perhaps `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 14):

Since [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) is defined for `std::pair` and it is based on `std::pair::first` and then `std::pair::second` (lexicographical), so your code is working as the standard. To sort it based on the second part of the `std::pair` you can try this:

```
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const std::pair<int, string> &x,
                                       const std::pair<int, string> &y)
{
    return x.second < y.second;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There is one "obvious" ordering of product types induced by the respective orderings of the components, and that is [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Definition):

```
(a, b) < (c, d)  <=>  a < c || (a == c && b < d)
```

This is the ordering used by `operator<` of `std::pair`. In your example, since all the first components are distinct, the ordering happens to be equal to the ordering of the first component. It gets more interesting if you have multiple occurences of the same value in the first component, in which the second component is used to break ties.

> How to make it do so for some class of mine as pair first?

You just have to define `operator<` for your type. But keep in mind that the second component *will* be considered if necessary and you might not want that overhead.

> Is there a way to sort by `second` using `std::sort`?

Yes, just use a [custom comparator functor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You can always do that if you don't want to use the default `operator<` for sorting.