# How to sort a list of pairs based on second element in decreasing order in c++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl, containers

I was wondering if there's a way to sort my list of pairs based on the second element. Here is a code:

```cpp
std::list<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>> words;

words.push_back(std::make_pair("aba", 23);
words.push_back(std::make_pair("ab", 20);
words.push_back(std::make_pair("aBa", 15);
words.push_back(std::make_pair("acC", 8);
words.push_back(std::make_pair("aaa", 23);
```

I would like to sort my list words based in the integer element in decreasing order so that my list would be like:

```
<"aba", 23>,<"aaa", 23>,<"ab", 20>,<"aBa", 15>,<"acC", 8>
```

Also, is it possible to sort them by both the first and second element such that it sorts by the second elements first (by integer value), and then if there's two or more pairs with the same second element (i.e. same integer value), then it will sort those based on the first element in alphabetical order, then the first 2 pairs on my sorted list above would swap, so:

```
<"aaa", 23>,<"aba", 23>,<"ab", 20>,<"aBa", 15>,<"acC", 8>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does std::sort work for list of pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816797/how-does-stdsort-work-for-list-of-pairs)

Comment: Using `std::vector` instead of `std::list` changes the answer, consider asking a fresh new answer for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to sort my **list** words based in the integer element in **decreasing order**

The sorting predicate must return `true` if the first element (i.e., the first pair) passed precedes the second one in your established order:

```
words.sort([](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
      return a.second > b.second;
});
```

Since you want to sort the list in *decreasing order*, the pair `a` will precede `b` if its second element (i.e., the `int`) is greater than `b`'s second element.

---

Note that [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) doesn't work for sorting an `std::list` because it requires *random access iterators* but `std::list` only provides *bidirectional iterators*.

---

> is it possible to sort them by both the first and second element such that it sorts by the second elements first (by integer value), and then if there's two or more pairs with the same second element (i.e. same integer value), then it will sort those based on the first element in alphabetical order

Assuming again decreasing order for the `int` element, just resort to the second element of the pairs when both `int` elements are the same:

```
   lst.sort([](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
      if (a.second > b.second)
         return true;
      if (a.second < b.second)
         return false;
      return a.first < b.first;
   });
```

or more concise thanks to [`std::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
lst.sort([](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
    return std::tie(b.second, a.first) < std::tie(a.second, a.first);
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to programming. So in my header file, do I put bool sortbysecond([](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
    return std::tie(b.second, a.first) < std::tie(a.second, a.first);
 }); and then on my cpp file, i can use it as sort(words.begin(), words.end(), sortbysecond);

Comment: @LilithX you use it as `words.sort(...)`. It is a *member function* of `std::list`. You can, however, use that predicate for `std::sort()` for sorting an `std::vector` as well.

Comment: If you want to write a function instead of a lambda it would be then `bool sortbysecond(const std::pair<string, unsigned int> &a, const std::pair<string, unsigned int> &b) { return std::tie(b.second, a.first) < std::tie(a.second, a.first); }`.

Comment: ah! It compiled successfully! Do you happen to know how i could iterate through my sorted list so I could print them out and see if they indeed sorted correctly? Thank you very much!

Comment: @LilithX `for (auto const& p: vec) std::cout << p.first << ' ' < p.second << '\n';` should do the trick. Remember that the elements are pairs.

Comment: it did indeed! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) has a member function [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) that is supposed to do the sorting.

One of its two overloads accepts custom comparison function:

```cpp
template <class Compare>
void sort(Compare comp);
```

which you can use as follows:

```cpp
words.sort([](const std::pair<string, unsigned int> &x,
              const std::pair<string, unsigned int> &y)
{
    return x.second > y.second;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

We are creating a compare function in bool which compares two pairs' second values and give the return bigger value first and simply done sorting with using that function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


bool compare(const pair<int,int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b){
    return a.second > b.second;
}

int main() {
    vector<pair<int,int>> v = {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {3, 8}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}};
    
    // sorting the vector of pairs by second value
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    
    // printing the sorted vector of pairs
    for(auto x: v){
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post "code only" answers. Explain what you are doing and why it solves the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).