# why sort stl in c++, sort on the basis of first value of vector of pairs in cpp

Tags: c++, c++14

***Suppose I have a vector of pair container:***

```
vector <pair <int, int>> vp = {{1, 2}. {4, 4}, {2, 3}};
```

Now I want to sort this container in acsending order using sort function:

```
sort(vp.begin(), vp.end());
```

Output:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}}
```

Now my question is that how the function works in-depth.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `std::sort` but the [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) in [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) which does [lexicographic comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)

Comment: duplicates: [How does std::sort work for list of pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23816797/995714), [Is std::pair<int, std::string> ordering well-defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2819245/995714)

Answer (score 2):

It sorts in accordance with the ordering of `std::pair<int, int>` class, which compares the first elements, and if they are *equivalent*, then compares the second elements. What algorithm is actually used to sort the vector is implementation-defined. Typically it is a mixture of a number of algorithms to adapt to different situations (number of elements, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses the elements `operator<` when not other comparator used. `std::sort` may use any sorting algorithm that meets the specification, most importantly the number of comparisons is of O(N·log(N)), where N = `std::distance(first, last)`.

[`std::pair<T1,T2>::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) compares `first` and only if they are equivalent compares their `second`.