# How will the sorting be done with vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

In the code `sort(A.begin(),A.end());` where `A` is defined as  `vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>> A;`.

If I call the `sort` method, then on which basis will sorting be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is std::pair<int, std::string> ordering well-defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819245/is-stdpairint-stdstring-ordering-well-defined)

Comment: It will sort on `std::pair::operator <`, details of which can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 3):

It will compare using the `operator <` for the `std::pair`, [specified here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

It compares the elements lexicographically on the `first` element first, and if they are equal, then on the `second` element.

Given the complex type here `pair<int,pair<int,int>>`, it may be a better idea to the give the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm a custom comparator. Make sure that the functor provided fulfils the requirements of the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept, that being *strict weak ordering*.