# How can I sort a pair of vector in some given range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, std-pair

I know how to sort pair of vectors using `std:sort(v.begin(), v.end());` But this will sort all the pairs of the vector.
But I want to sort the vector in a specified range.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long

using namespace std;

bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b)
{
       return a.second>b.second;
}


int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    
    ll a[n];
    ll b[n];
    
    vector<pair<ll, ll>> v;
    vector<pair<ll, ll>>::iterator itr;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v.push_back(make_pair(a[i],b[i]));
    }
    
    //sorting the pair in descending order with second element
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortbysecdesc);
    
 
    for (itr=v.begin(); itr!=v.end(); itr++) {
        
        /* Logic to be implement */
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code explanation- Here I'm taking input 2 arrays and making a pair of vector by combining `first_array[i]` element with `second_element[i]` element.
Such as - `first_array = {1, 5, 4, 9}` and `second_array = {2, 10, 5, 7}` then the vector of pair's will be of **size = 2*size_of(first/second array)** and elements will be `[{1, 2}, {5, 10}, {4, 5}, {9, 7}]`.
Then I'm sorting these pair in descending order according to second elements of pairs i.e, all elements of second array.

Now I wanna sort the vector form where second elements are equal.

eg - if the vector is `[{1,6} , {4,5}, {3,5}, {8,5}, {1,1}]`. Here 5 occurs three time in second element of pair so sort their first index in ascending order.
Expected result - `[{1,6} , {3,5}, {4,5}, {8,5}, {1,1}]`

Note - We had already sorted the second element in descending order.

Comment: Your code have some of the *bad* habits commonly show-cased on so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites. Please don't use such sites to learn anything, that's not what they're for (unless you want to know how bad and often invalid code look like, as is the case with your program (both the bad habits and being invalid C++)).

Comment: Have you considered simply adding `if(a.second == b.second) { return a.first < a.second; }` section to your comparator, `sortbysecdesc()`?

Comment: @Frank hey that works fine :) but if wanna compare if second element of the final vector occurs more than once :(

Comment: @Uttam, that's what `if(a.first == a.second)` does. it detects when the second element happens more than once.

Comment: Btw, if you could invert the order of elements in your pairs (that is, pair<b, a> instead of <a, b>), the vector would sort automatically in just the way you want it to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819287/10908201

Comment: @DL33 this looks somewhat I'm looking for :) Can you please post this in answer section after modifying my entire code

Comment: pair of vectors != vector of pairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is something like the following

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::sort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
           []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 )
           {
               return std::tie( p2.second, p1.first ) < std::tie( p1.second, p2.first );
           } );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<long long, long long>> v =
    {
        {1,6} , {4,5}, {3,5}, {8,5}, {1,1}
    };
    
    std::sort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
               []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 )
               {
                    return std::tie( p2.second, p1.first ) <
                           std::tie( p1.second, p2.first );
               } );
               
    for ( const auto &p : v )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
               
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ 1, 6 } { 3, 5 } { 4, 5 } { 8, 5 } { 1, 1 }
```

Comment: As OP mixes descending and ascending order, we have to mix parameters too: `return std::tie(p2.second, p1.first) < std::tie(p1.second, p2.first);`.

Comment: I tried your approach too. But :( 
Can you please head to this practice question https://www.codechef.com/UAPRAC/problems/PSORT3

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. I have updated the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow hey thankyou so much for your help :) but why are you using `const` everywhere and what does std:tie() do. Can you please explain

Comment: Then I will mark this ans the accepted ans :) But for now I am doing upvote

Answer (score 3):

You have to update your sorting function. Try this.

```
bool sortbysecdesc(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b)
{
       return a.second == b.second ? a.first < b.first : a.second > b.second;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z9jnjPhb3)

Comment: bro but my `sortbysecdesc` function works fine. I want to check the final vector of pairs and if 2nd element of a vector occurs more than one then I wanna sort that much of first element of vector in ascending order

Comment: @Uttam: Have you tried proposed answer?

Comment: @SumitJha: function name should be changed though (or lambda used to avoid name completely ;-) ).

Comment: @Jarod42 yup but it didn't worked or maybe I'm doing anything wrong can you please post the entire code as I asked in question.

Comment: @Uttam: If **you** provided MCVE, you just have to replace your function by this one. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/976e55c0908f74a8) added anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42 yep I tried that but it gave wrong ans. See this practice question https://www.codechef.com/UAPRAC/problems/PSORT3

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for adding the demo.

Comment: @Uttam Could you give an example that is not working by simply replacing your `sortbysecdesc`with this one.

Comment: @Uttam: Issue might come from the way you output result too (extra space at the end for example).

Comment: @Sumit i'm alao not getting why the code is not passing all the test case

Comment: @Uttam I think the problem is how you collect data into vector using cin. https://godbolt.org/z/G7hc6nxMT . I have updated the demo with comments. Have a look.